# Is there a pretty printer / code formatter for C# (as part of build system)?

Tags: c#, pretty-print

Is there a pretty printer / code formatter for C# (as part of build system)?  Read as: "lives outside of Visual Studio".  It seems like there are plenty of these kinds of things for Java, C++/C, Go -- so it seems more than reasonable that C# should also have some code formatter that lives outside of the IDE?

(I'd actually like to couple the formatter with something like StyleCop, and have devs run it as part of the process before a commit).

NOTE: Not syntax highlighting, as in code in a web page.  Instead, a *Code beautifier*, or code pretty printer, which would take code and format it to a style/standard coding format... which StyleCop does a style check to see if the code meets the format.

Comment: @Alvin That’s unhelpful. Try googling for them yourself and see what relevant/garbage ratio you find. Note, OP isn’t searching for a syntax highlighter for websites, they’re looking for a tool to re-format code properly to conform to style guidelines.

Comment: @Adriano Nope, that’s unrelated.

Comment: @AlvinWong I got into an infinite loop because Googling [c# prettier code formatter](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+prettier+code+formatter) leads me to this exact same page.

Answer (score 27):

There finally is; [Csharpier](https://csharpier.com/)!

It was originally ported from the popular [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) and it is **just** a code formatter for C#. It can run from the command line and is not tied to an IDE nor an extension, although support for these exists as well. You can make it run as a part of a git-hook to for example automatically format changed files on git commit.

Some benefits of choosing Csharpier over other formatting tools are:

- It breaks long lines, unlike most formatters (such as [dotnet-format](https://github.com/dotnet/format/issues/246))
- It doesn't preserve the original formatting. This benefit is perhaps best explained by reading the section [Building and enforcing a style guide](https://prettier.io/docs/en/why-prettier.html) on the Prettier web page.

Comment: This is more my speed!

Answer (score 11):

JetBrains also makes a free command line tool named [CleanupCode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/CleanupCode.html) that formats c# based on [.editorconfig](https://editorconfig.org/) settings. I wrote a wrapper utility for it named [ReGitLint](https://github.com/sethreno/ReGitLint#regitlint) that makes it easier and faster to run as a pre-commit hook or on the build server. This can help out a lot if you've got teammates using Visual Studio Code where ReSharper isn't an option.

To get up and going just run the following commands

```
dotnet tool install JetBrains.ReSharper.GlobalTools
dotnet tool install ReGitLint
```

then add the following to .git/hooks/pre-commit

```
#!/bin/sh
dotnet regitlint -f staged --fail-on-diff
```

To enforce formatting on jenkins add this to your build script

```
dotnet tool restore
dotnet regitlint --jenkins
```

For more options check out the [readme](https://github.com/sethreno/ReGitLint#regitlint)

Comment: this should be accepted answer, nice! i'm glad this is a free tool which should help adoption throughout our team

Comment: If you're not already down with ReSharper, [this link explaining `.editorconfig` setup](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Using_EditorConfig.html) might be useful. Great tool, though I wish it were Free & open source. (The first hit is always free, as they say.)

Answer (score 6):

### .NET 6+ — `dotnet format`:

10 years after this question was asked, the .NET SDK now comes with a built-in formatting command: `dotnet format` — see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-format) and [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/format) repo for more information.

`dotnet format` used to be a third-party tool which eventually got merged into the official .NET SDK, starting from .NET 6 — see [anouncement](https://github.com/dotnet/format/issues/1268).

### Usage:

You can run the command in any directory that has a `.csproj` or `.sln` file present, all C# (or VB.NET) files across the solution/project will be formatted:

```bash
dotnet format
```

Or you can specifically run it for individual files:

```bash
dotnet format --include Program.cs
```

The formatting will be based on preferences outlined in an `.editorconfig` file, if you have one present, otherwise it'll use its own defaults.

Answer (score 5):

For .NET SDK projects the [dotnet format command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-format) can be used.

> dotnet format is a code formatter that applies style preferences to a project or solution. Preferences will be read from an `.editorconfig` file, if present, otherwise a default set of preferences will be used.

It may also work for classic .NET Framework projects if the project does not import things that are not available on .NET SDK, like text templating msbuild targets.

The dotnet format source repository is located [on GitHub dotnet/format](https://github.com/dotnet/format).

The `.editorconfig` rules are [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/), and can be exported from and will be used by Visual Studio too.

Answer (score 4):

The first that comes to mind is [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). However, it's an add-in to VS which isn't what you were asking for. I'm not sure if you can set it up to auto-format on save.

From their [website](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html):

> ReSharper can reformat an arbitrary selected block of code, all code
>   in the current file, all files in a directory, or even in the entire
>   project or solution, according to your Code Style preferences.
>   ReSharper provides distinct formatting options for C#, VB.NET,
>   JavaScript, CSS and XML code. Reformatting affects braces layout,
>   blank lines, line wrapping and line breaks, spaces in various
>   contexts, indentation, aligning multiple constructs, and a lot more
>   options that you can fine-tune in the ReSharper Options dialog box.

Comment: It can't - I asked a similar question on SO (oops).

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: NArrange is not developed any more (see also https://github.com/MarcStan/narrange for a slightly newer fork).

---

To automate code formatting (kind of micro refactoring) during build you need a tool you can run from command line (and you can easily integrate in msbuild).

A good one if your needing isn't too advanced (authors define it as *beautifier*) is [NArrange](http://www.narrange.net/). It fully supports C# and VB.NET for Framework 2.0 but many widely used features of newer language versions are supported too.

> NArrange is a .NET code beautifier that automatically organizes code members and elements within .NET classes.

Comment: This looks to be dead

Comment: @andrewjboyd true, there is a fork (https://github.com/MarcStan/narrange) slightly newer but the project has been abandoned a long time ago.

Comment: (note that this answer is 9 years old)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an existing and unusual style guideline about whitespaces and brace placements [AStyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) is probably flexible enough to match it. AStyle is not C# specific, it can do many c-like languages.

[NArrange](http://www.narrange.net/doc/index.htm) is also good if it happens to match your style guidelines. It can be a more aggressive, for example it can put parts of your classes into different regions and sort your methods.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a code formatter tool that use Roslyn to automatically rewrite source code according to their guidelines.
Please check that link
https://github.com/dotnet/codeformatter

Comment: Are you using this successfully on a current project There's an issue on that project that basically says it's dead. A [comment in an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/codeformatter/issues/267#issuecomment-501499109) on that project suggests using [dotnet-format](https://github.com/dotnet/format), which seems to be active.

Comment: I'm not using that currently, I just thought of sharing that there is something doing that requirment, going to have a look at dotnet-format.

Answer (score -1):

You can now use https://www.npmjs.com/package/narrange leveraging the power of node.js
Super simple, configurable setup :)

```
const { createNArrange } = require("narrange");
const path = require("path");

createNArrange({
  srcPath: path.join(__dirname, "src/apps/mango"),
  configFilePath: path.join(__dirname, "config/NArrange.xml")
});
```

Comment: This appears to be a wrapper around NArrange v0.2.9, created by a different author than the original software.